# Nested data structures in Go - Python equivalent

Tags: json, go, maps

I can create this data structure in Python really easily:

```
data = {'Locations': [],
 'Dates': [],
 'Properties': [{'key': 'data1', 'value': 'data2'}],
 'Category': 'all'}
```

Which can then be marshalled to JSON in Python just as easily. e.g.

```
print json.dumps(data)

{"Category": "all", "Dates": [], "Locations": [], "Properties": [{"value": "data2", "key": "data1"}]}
```

However, I'm tearing my hair out trying to create the same structure then convert it to JSON in Go. Go looks to be very promising and just what I need for creating cross platform applications, but boy this stuff seems to be frustratingly difficult.

This is what I've tried, however I cant get the structure to include the square brackets that should surround the properties element.

```
import (
"fmt"
"encoding/json"
)

func main() {

data := map[string]interface{}{"Offset": "0", "Properties": map[string]string{"value": "data2", "key": "data1"}, "Category": "all", "Locations": []string{}, "Dates": []string{} }
    data_json, _ := json.Marshal(data)
fmt.Println(string(data_json))
}
```

Which outputs:

```
{"Category":"all","Dates":[],"Locations":[],"Offset":"0","Properties":{"key":"data1","value":"data2"}}
```

Heres a demo: http://play.golang.org/p/49Kytg6v_C

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a slice of `map[string]string`:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{
    "Offset":     "0",
    "Properties": []map[string]string{{"value": "data2", "key": "data1"}},
    "Category":   "all",
    "Locations":  []string{},
    "Dates":      []string{},
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/YnPLHSV4wq)

Comment: Thank you so much - I've been going round in circles with this for hours.

Comment: If the type info is making it too noisy (ie: for more complicated structures), don't forget you can define types to simply the map literal syntax.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/FCjaDqdIUw

Answer (score 2):

While OneOfOne's solution works in a literal sense, with Go's static typing you likely want a struct.

```
// The `json:"stuff"` will cause it to use that json tag when reading or writing json.
type Property struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
    Val string `json:"value"`
}

// ,omitempty allows it to ignore the empty string "" when writing json,
// I put this here because one of your json examples had no Offset field
// you can do this with other fields too.
type MyType struct {
    Offset     string `json:",omitempty"`
    Properties []Property
    Category   string
    Locations  []string
    Dates      []string
}
```

Of course, you could also consider using built-in or custom Go types for some of those fields, such as using a `[]time.Time` for the Dates field. This makes it more difficult to just read/write arbitrary json ad-hoc or on the fly, but since you need to have some logic somewhere to interpret those fields, in Go it generally makes much more sense to treat it as a struct most of the time.

To read in/put out the json, you would then do

```
import "encoding/json"
//...
stuff := MyType{}
json.Unmarshal(myJsonData, &stuff)
// stuff is now { [{data1 data2}] all [] []}
out,_ := json.Marshal(stuff)
// string(out) is now {"Properties":[{"key":"data1","value":"data2"}],
// "Category":"all","Locations":[],"Dates":[]}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/jIHgXmY13R